# How to convert 8Bit to decimal bar from 0 to 15?

Tags: c, atmega

Okay, here's what I'm trying to program in C.

I have an 8bit binary signal from an ADC on an ATmega32.

Now I want to convert that signal into an bar with 15LED's that increases the higher the input value is. 
So basically I want to cut my 8bit signal down to a 4bit one, convert it to decimal and show it at an increasing bar.

I first had the idea to check if my input is in a specific range (which would be always a range of 255/15) but I just couldn't figure out how.

Just checking if the input is higher than a particular value won't work because in that way there could be more than one condition at a time true.

Have you any idea how I could solve that? Any help is highly appreciated. ;)
Thank you!

Comment: Why does just diving by 17 not work? (255/17 == 15 bars).

Comment: Right-shift the value by 4, then in a loop, turn on/off the nth led whether or not the value is greater than the nth interval (`value > n * input >> 4`).

Comment: @Mark Stevens: Hmm, but when doing so, how can I be sure that the resulting number is always a full number? If using float I'll end up with the same problem of checking if the number is in a specific range.

Comment: Integer division in C always results in an integer.  You'll only get a float if you do `255 / 17.0`.

Comment: @user1792524: what tom said. you of course will have some quantization, but there's no way around it unless you have 255 bars (OK, you still have the ADC quant); I didn't get that you were trying to figure out how to enable the LEDs, only scale the ADC output. H2C03 has the right solution for that.

Comment: @tomlogic: Thanks! And after that I would use a switch case to determinate in which "state" the bar should be. But that's still a 15 lines of code. H2CO3s solution would be better, but I don't understand it fully. Why exactly shift by the value of 4?

Comment: @user1792524 Actually, H2CO3's solution does both - it's quite elegant.

Comment: @MarkStevens: it seems so, but since I'm not quite familiar with C it's a little bit abstract.. (edit: sure, the value of 4 is because I just need 4 bit.. I'm starting to look trough that a bit)

Comment: `>>1` is deviding by `2`, `<<1` is multiplying by `2`. So `>>4` is deviding by `16`, what is what you actually want for scaling down your 8bit value to 4bit (`2^8/2^4=2^4=16`). @Cramstyler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
uint8_t adc = GET_ADC_VALUE();

// Say LED is a 16-bit register

LED = (adc ? (1U << ((adc >> 4) + 1)) - 1 : 0x000);
```

So only ADC value `0` has all LEDs off, all other ADC values power on 1 to 16 LEDs. This has the advantage of not using any division (ATmega has no divisor instruction).

**EDIT:** The above code actually assumes 16 LEDs, if you have 15 LEDs just do:

```
LED= (1U << (adc >> 4)) - 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Works perfectly. (I do not understand the whole thing though, but there's time tomorrow to figure that out).